# Cursor randomly jumps around

Tags: gnome, touchpad, laptop, 15.10, cursor

Since I upgraded from Ubuntu GNOME 15.04 with GNOME 3.16 to Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18 (and also dropped some chocolate cake into my computer) I have noticed the cursor randomly jumping around (I have a touchpad built-into my laptop), sometimes it happens when I click, sometimes not, but it is getting rather annoying, especially the fact that when I want to upvote something here I downvote it (and vice versa)! So is there any way of fixing this issue? Or has the chocolate finally taken control?

I would like to first try to figure out if this is a software issue before I attempt to dismantle my computer (because it could just be after the upgrading something went wrong)?

Comment: It's probably the vodka. Anyhow, you could take the laptop apart (it's generally not too difficult) and check to see if there are any crumbs in there. They're usually easy enough to replace if they're too far gone. It's just a ribbon cable and a few screws. (I used to drink, I've replaced a few.)

Comment: @KGIII: So you think that it's definitely a hardware and not a software issue then?

Comment: Well, if you think that, you should probably go and file a bug report against `chocolate-cake-crumbs`'s touchpad interface... **;-D**

Comment: @ParanoidPanda, given the likelihood of you having done something to your computer (pretty high, considering your other posts *grins*) then, no, I'm unable to be certain but I'd certainly consider it - with the evidence given. I'm assuming the touch pad is well cleaned (visibly) and you've made no changes to your drivers or settings. If that's the case then dismantling the touch pad and blowing it out with canned air (keeping the can upright and using short burst) would be a good place to start.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda I also experience this wobbly cursor issue, but only when the laptop is  charging! I googled it and found it was due to some current seepage issue(I don't remember), so I settled for an external mouse...